# Export all lists to excel

Tags: list, excel, export, bulk

I have three different list seperated by Area (NY, NJ, and CT) is there a way to build a report in the database that will pull all records from all lists? I exported all three to excel one by one, but they are all formatted different which makes combining them all an absolute nightmare. I need the ability to pull 1 bulk report that pulls from all lists.

Comment: Does all the tree lists has same field schema?

Comment: what is field schema?

Comment: field structure or the list of columns in all the lists

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft Access you can link all 3 SharePoints lists, built a Query and Export whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct out of the box way to do this. One option is

1. Export first list to Excel
2. Now change the connection name to List1
3. Export second list to Excel. Here choose new WorkSheet instead of WorkBook
4. Change the connection name to List2
5. Export third list to Excel and choose new WorkSheet
6. Change the connection name to List3

Now you can use Excel operations to combine the three sheets into one.